# jquery or javascript how to find if an array contains an object and that object has a name with a specified value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I am trying to build an array of objects to save a menu's state in a cookie but it is not updating because it is not finding the proper index containing the object I need to update visibility for. What am I doing wrong and/or can you point me in the right direction?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var menu = new Array();
    $("#vertical-nav .head").click(function() {
        var c = $(this).next().attr('name');
        $(this).next().slideToggle("slow", function() {
            if ( $(this).next().is(':visible') ) {
                menu.push({
                    name: c,
                    visible: true,
                });
            } else {
                var index = $.inArray(c, menu);
                console.log("INDEX: " + index);
                menu[index] = { name: c, visible:false };
            }
        });
        console.log(menu);
    });
});
```

***This is what I ended up with:***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var menu = new Array();
    if ( $.cookie('menu') ) {
        var items = JSON.parse($.cookie('menu'));
        for ( var item in items ) {
            if ( items[item].visible ) {
                $("div[name='" + items[item].name + "']").show();
            }
            menu.push(items[item]);
        }
    }

    $("#vertical-nav .head").click(function() {
        var c = $(this).next().attr('name');
        if ( $(this).next().is(":visible") ) {
            hide(this, c);
        } else {
            show(this, c);
        }
    });

    function show(obj, c) {
        $(obj).next().slideDown('slow', function() {
            var elementExists = false;
            if ( menu.length > 0 ) {
                for ( var item in menu ) {
                    if ( menu[item].name == c ) {
                        elementExists = true;
                        menu[item].visible = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if ( !elementExists ) {
                menu.push({
                    name: c,
                    visible: true,
                });
            }
            $.cookie('menu', JSON.stringify(menu));
        });
    }

    function hide(obj, c) {
        $(obj).next().slideUp('slow', function() {
            if ( menu.length > 0 ) {
                for ( var item in menu ) {
                    if ( menu[item].name == c ) {
                        menu[item].visible = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            $.cookie('menu', JSON.stringify(menu));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I dont have time to write up an example at the moment, but check out jQuery's grep function, it most likely contains what you are looking for: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/

Comment: `console.log(menu)` at the end is happening before your if statement that modifies `menu`. Stick it inside a setTimeout with a 5 second delay and you'll see what i mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily do this:

```
if (menu.length > 0) {
    for (var item in menu) {
        if (menu[item].name=="some text") alert("Found it!");
    }
}
```

What I would consider is instead of `[{name: "item"; visible: true}]` is switch to a key/value pair.  You can then use `{"item": true}`, but this is limited to only storing the visible value and no extra info can be stored in the key.  To solve this, try {"item": {visible: true}}.  Here's an example of detection in JS using this approach:

```
if (menu.length > 0) {
    for (var item in menu) {
        var strVisible="hidden";
        if (menu[item].visible==true) strVisible="visible";
        alert(item+" is "+strVisible);
    }
}
```